# Profile.GetProfile() on Base Class

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, membership-provider

I have a base page (inherited from System.Web.UI.Page and all my pages inherit from this base page) in my .Net web application and at the moment if I put the following methods:

```
protected int GetProfileTenant()
    {
        try
        {
            ProfileCommon p = Profile.GetProfile(Profile.UserName);
            return Convert.ToInt32(p.TenantID);
        }
        catch
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

the error come up saying that "the Name Profile does not existin the current context".

This methods if I put this into the page (inherited from the base page clas) works well (no issue).

Any ideas?

Thanks

Thanks

Comment: Next time, please add a tag that describes the technology you're using, since "membership-provider" is rather uninformational. This time I added asp.net for you.

Answer (score 1):

Add System.web namespace in the class.
and try this

```
HttpContext.Current.Profile.UserName
```

Comment: And over 1 year later, this comment helps me a great deal. I was trying to do something similar on a Base Page (get a different Profile Property however) and this started me down the right path. ProfileCommon does not work because it is a dynamically created Profile class that will NOT have profile information for the current user (including profile properties like UserName).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a clear-cut answer for you, but there is some "magic" happening in the way profiles work (a class matching your profile properties gets generated). Apparently the Profile property gets injected into the top level page class. Have you tried using *HttpContext.Current.Profile* instead?